# Accessing AuthorizationAttribute within Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a custom AuthorizeAttribute written in MVC. I have it applied to a controller for security. In that AuthorizeAttribute class I have written are several variables I gathered from a web service call I would like to access inside the controller to prevent having to call the web service again. Is this possible?

Comment: do you want to access only `authorization` attribute in your controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best approach would be to use `HttpContext.Current.Items` for storing those variables because that data will only be valid for a single http request. Something like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User.Identity == null) return false;
        if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated) return false;

        var user = new WSUser(); //get this from your webservice
        if(user == null) return false;

        httpContext.Items.Add("prop", user.Property);

        return user.Authorized;
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var property = (string) HttpContext.Items["prop"];
        return View();
    }
}
```

You would also want to encapsulate logic for storing and retrieving items from `HttpContext.Current` into a separate class to keep the code clean and to follow [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 0):

You could save these variables in a static class to store it. But, a elegant solution would be to have a modelbinder object that you call like parameter in your controller and that read the static class and return the properties that you need.
Perhaps, if you are applying security, the best will be that call the webservices each once.

[Reference for your custom model binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder)